# VBA Web Scraping: macro stops when I run it but not in debugging mode

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I have tried few thing like waiting for 1 to 10 seconds before the linecode with issue "Html.querySelector("a[href='#tab-import']").Click" where it stops or adding a "loop" until the page charges but I dont know why it only works in debugging mode.

HTML source:

```
<a href="#tab-import" data-toggle="tab">Import</a>
```

The error is 91: Object variable not set.

My code with cemented credentials

```
Sub Direnet()
    Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer

    'create a new instance of ie
    Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

    'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
    ieApp.Visible = True

    'go to the page we want
    ieApp.Navigate "http://direnetdemos.com/casagarza-op/admin/index.php?route=tool/export_import&token=9reP7LOHg0SMChCYFBbcLPoQSjiQ72W1"

    Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

    With ieApp
        .document.all.Item("input-username").Value = "xxxx"
        .document.all.Item("input-password").Value = "xxxx"
        .document.forms(0).submit

        Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

        'Click en pestaña Import
        Dim Html As HTMLDocument

        Set Html = ieApp.document

        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

        Html.querySelector("a[href='#tab-import']").Click
        Html.querySelectorAll("input[name='incremental']")(1).Click
        Html.querySelector("input[id='upload']").Click
        Html.querySelector("a[onclick='uploadData();']").Click

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If it runs in debug/step-through mode but not when run straight through that often indicates a timing issue.  The page may be loaded but the element you're trying to access hasn't yet been created: it may be built dynamically via scripting.  You need either to add a "wait" or use some kind of loop to detect when the element is present.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the html source code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click something you should wait for the browser to be "ready" again:

```
Html.querySelector("a[href='#tab-import']").Click

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until Not ieApp.Busy And ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE 

Html.querySelectorAll("input[name='incremental']")(1).Click

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until Not ieApp.Busy And ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Html.querySelector("input[id='upload']").Click

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until Not ieApp.Busy And ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE 

Html.querySelector("a[onclick='uploadData();']").Click

Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until Not ieApp.Busy And ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
```

---

Also, don't use `Application.Wait` for this kind of thing - it literally just freezes code execution for a given time. It doesn't allow events to process or have any kind of link to the broswer's ready state.

Comment: Not sure you can reliably use readyState if there are (eg) additional calls being made or dynamic content being constructed after the page sources are loaded?

Comment: I’m not sure you can use VBA to reliably manipulate IE at all! Lol but yes your point is valid - if the click triggers an AJAX call for example the readystate won’t change. You would have to write a loop to check the element is there, which obviously comes with a whole new set of timing problems!

Answer (score 0):

Well it finally worked moving this linecode "IE.Visible = True" a few lines after. Thank you very much for all.